# Cannot deploy apps in Openshift Online: `Error syncing pod: FailedSync`

Tags: docker, openshift, openshift-online

So I'm new to Openshift Online, and I'm looking to deploy a test image that when run simply runs a C++ native executable that says `Hello world!`.

After pushing the built docker image to the docker hub and creating an app that uses that image, I've waited for it to deploy. At some point in the process, a warning event arises stating

```
Error syncing pod, Reason: FailedSync
```

Then, the deployment stalls at pending until the deadline runs out, and it reports the deployment failed.

As far as I know, I can't have done anything wrong. I simply created an app with the default settings that uses an image.

The only thing that could be happening is that the image runs as root, which, upon creating the app, caused a warning.

```
WARNING: Image "me/blahblah:test" runs as the 'root' user which may not be permitted by your cluster administrator.
```

However, this doesn't seem to be causing the problem, since it hasn't even deployed the app by the time the process stalls until it reaches the deadline.

I'll add any extra information that could lead to the problem being solved.

Comment: OpenShift Online is still going through periods of degraded performance which could cause that. The issues are still being investigated to come up with permanent solution. You can track status at https://status.starter.openshift.com/

Comment: The warning about ``root`` is separate and will not be an issue so long as your application doesn't try and write to filesystem directories which do require root, or try and do others things that required ``root``. This is because container will be forced to run as a non ``root`` user.

Comment: Read guidelines for creating images at https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/latest/creating_images/guidelines.html